# What is Control Flattened Device Tree of U-Boot?

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot, firmware

According to this [blog](https://pacificsimplicity.ca/blog/verified-boot-%E2%80%93-introduction-u-boot%E2%80%99s-secure-boot) and Uboot docs, U-boot.bin contains a device tree called Control FDT(Flattened Device Tree). Where can I find this dtb or its source in U-boot source tree? Can you supply me an example or a doc about ctrl-FDT (FDT in the U-Boot) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A device tree is a description of the hardware of your system. This description is used to determine which drivers to load and how to configure them to work with your hardware. Both U-Boot and Linux use device trees. The device tree source (*.dts) is translated to a device tree binary (*.dtb) using the device tree compiler. The device tree sources for U-Boot are in

```
arch/${ARCH}/dts
```

Unfortunately not all drivers in U-Boot are converted to use this model yet. All new drivers should use it.

https://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Usage may be a good initial reading.